# Function call with button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have a problem with my implementation of a button meant to add functionality to a piece of code. It seems to be working, but why do the **Date** and **Checkbox** elements not behave like the ones in the first row?

It should calculate the difference in the date and cross the other `<td>`. I need to call the `Date` and `Checkbox` properties with my add button.

My code is below. How can I fix it? Thank you for your time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        margin: 100px;
    }

    table,
    td,
    th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }

        table td.crossed {
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, transparent, red, transparent);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, transparent, red, transparent);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, transparent, red, transparent);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent, red, transparent);
        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            <input style="margin-top:-200px; padding:10px" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow()" />
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="date" id="mydate">
        </td>
        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    function createRowColumn(row) {
        var column = document.createElement("td");
        row.appendChild(column);
        return column;
    }


    function addRow() {
        var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
        var numericColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
        var checkColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
        var dateColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
        var emptyColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
        var removeColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);

        var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkColumn.appendChild(checkbox);

        var datebox = document.createElement("input");
        datebox.setAttribute("type", "date");

        dateColumn.appendChild(datebox);

        emptyColumn.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");

        var remove = document.createElement("input");
        remove.setAttribute("type", "button");
        remove.setAttribute("value", "Delete Row");
        remove.setAttribute("onClick", "deleteRow(this)");
        removeColumn.appendChild(remove);

        var table = document.getElementById('t1');
        var tbody = table.querySelector('tbody') || table;
        var count = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
        numericColumn.innerText = count.toLocaleString() + '.';

        tbody.appendChild(newrow);
    }

    function deleteRow(button) {
        var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
        var tbody = row.parentNode;
        tbody.removeChild(row);


        var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var currentRow = rows[i];
            currentRow.childNodes[0].innerText = i.toLocaleString() + '.';
        }

    }
    var cb = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0];
    var td = document.querySelectorAll("td[contenteditable]")[0];

    cb.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (cb.checked) td.classList.add("crossed");
        else td.classList.remove("crossed");
    });

    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById('mydate').onchange = function () {
            var selectedDateFromCalendar = new Date(this.value);

            var currentdate = new Date();

            var Diff = new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate;

            var diffDays = Math.ceil(Diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

            if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate < 0) {
                alert("out of date");
            }
            else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate >= 1) {
                alert("last " + diffDays + " day");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you take element by id! `getElementById` and id's are unique!! Your jQuery is stuck on the first id.. it can't recognise the other. Try using multiple id's or classes!!

Big edit here:

Well, sorry for the time but I had some work and no time for Stack. Your problem is a bit tricky if you don't want to "loop and mess with the multiple classes" you can get some reference about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

So using the above QA, here is following snippet for the tricky solution, where we have to "add and fire" events in each new dynamically created element.

Check that I added 'myclass' not only in the first row but and on the following dynamically created ones!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-2.1.1.min.js'></script>

    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 100px;
        }

        table,
        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        table td.crossed {
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, transparent, red, transparent);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, transparent, red, transparent);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top left, transparent, red, transparent);
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, transparent, red, transparent);
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="t1">
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th>
            <input style="margin-top:-200px; padding:10px" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow()" />
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1.</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="date" id="mydate" class="myclass">
        </td>
        <td contenteditable='true'></td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    function createRowColumn(row) {
        var column = document.createElement("td");
        row.appendChild(column);
        return column;
    }


    function addRow() {
        var newrow = document.createElement("tr");
        var numericColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
        var checkColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
        var dateColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
        var emptyColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);
        var removeColumn = createRowColumn(newrow);

        var checkbox = document.createElement("input");
        checkbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        checkColumn.appendChild(checkbox);

        var datebox = document.createElement("input");
        datebox.setAttribute("type", "date");
        datebox.setAttribute("class", "myclass");

        dateColumn.appendChild(datebox);

        emptyColumn.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");

        var remove = document.createElement("input");
        remove.setAttribute("type", "button");
        remove.setAttribute("value", "Delete Row");
        remove.setAttribute("onClick", "deleteRow(this)");
        removeColumn.appendChild(remove);

        var table = document.getElementById('t1');
        var tbody = table.querySelector('tbody') || table;
        var count = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
        numericColumn.innerText = count.toLocaleString() + '.';

        tbody.appendChild(newrow);
    }

    function deleteRow(button) {
        var row = button.parentNode.parentNode;
        var tbody = row.parentNode;
        tbody.removeChild(row);


        var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var currentRow = rows[i];
            currentRow.childNodes[0].innerText = i.toLocaleString() + '.';
        }

    }
    var cb = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')[0];
    var td = document.querySelectorAll("td[contenteditable]")[0];

    cb.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (cb.checked) td.classList.add("crossed");
        else td.classList.remove("crossed");
    });

    function hasClass(elem, className) {
        return elem.className.split(' ').indexOf(className) > -1;
    }

    document.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
        if (hasClass(e.target, 'myclass')) {
            var selectedDateFromCalendar = new Date(e.target.value);

            var currentdate = new Date();

            var Diff = new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate;

            var diffDays = Math.ceil(Diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

            if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate < 0) {
                alert("out of date");
            }
            else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate >= 1) {
                alert("last " + diffDays + " day");
            }
        }

    }, false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

with help from [ram swaroop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1385441/ram-swaroop) , Dave and Sime Vidas

have a nice day!

Comment: do I use document.querySelectorAll() for solving my problem? @user5626587